# Can I disable and then re-enable Redis AOF without losing data?

Tags: redis

I currently have a Redis 6.2.4 cluster (3 masters + 3 replicas) with the following configuration for persistence

```
dbfilename "dump.rdb"
save 700 1
save 600 10000

appendonly yes
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
appendfsync everysec
```

I would like to try to disable the AOF writing and re-enable it later to debug disk writing performances.
If I execute the `CONFIG SET appendonly no` and `CONFIG SET appendonly yes` to a running instance, making sure it is never restarted, will the next AOF rewrite contain all the database data or do I lose the data written while AOF was off?

`aof-use-rdb-preamble` is set to `yes` (as default), but If I understand correctly only the AOF file is used for the AOF rewrite, so the data that was never written will be lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enable *appendonly* (by setting `config set appendonly yes`), Redis starts an AOF rewrite job in the background. So all changes will be kept, and you lose nothing. Of course, you need to ensure Redis is alive.